# scrollview can not scroll to the bottom

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, scroll, uitextview

i have a scrollview and a textview above it. the textview's scroll is disable. when the textview.contentSize.height over the scrollview frame, the scrollview can not scroll to the bottom.

do anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly, i've solved this problem. This problem happen because the scrollview.contentSize < scrollview.frame, so, to make it can scroll until the bottom (in my case, until the last end in textview), i set the scrollview.contentSize > scrollview.frame

Answer (score 0):

Because textview receives touches instead of scrollview?

Comment: how can i make the scrollview get the touches?the textview is a subview of the scrollview

Comment: It gets them by default, if not overlapped by other view.

Comment: so, how can i make this scrollview scroll to bottom?